# Adding values to FormData - javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, react.js

```
let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('File', document.file);
  formData.append('DocumentType', document.documentType);

  product = {
    ...values,
    productType: productT,
  };

  for (var key in product) {
    if (key != 'createdDate' && key != 'expirationDate') {
      formData.append(key, product[key]);
    } else {
      formData.append(key, new Date(product[key]).toUTCString());
    }
  }

  await createproduct(formData);
```

I need to send file and other data about product in one request so I added all the stuffs in `FormData`, and I have issues only with `Dates`, I must convert it to `date` because somehow it get confused if I don't convert it.

Can I somehow refactor this code to do this part about dates more elegant, `if condition` in `for loop` somehow smells bad..

P.S EDIT:

```
for (var key in product) {
   const transform = DateTransformer[key];
   formData.append(key, transform ? transform[product[key]] : product[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Transformation rules

Especially useful if there are many fields and each needs a unique rule.

```
const dateToUTCString = d => new Date(d).toUTCString();

const DataTransformer = {
  createdDate: dateToUTCString,
  expirationDate: dateToUTCString,
};

// [...]

for (const [key, calue] of Object.entries(product)) {
  const transform = DataTransformer[key];
  formData.append(key, transform ? transform(value) : value);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this works..

Comment: The code is a standard JavaScript so I'm not sure what to clarify.